# Running a Javascript function from PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am working on an Ajax project. There are many functions that could be implemented if we could run javascript function from php script like this:

```
   <?php

   if(isset($_REQUEST['change-div))
   {
   echo'<script>  UpdateDiv("divId"); // function to change the text of the div on ajax page
   </script>';
   }

   ?>
```

But it doesn't work the javascript code is just echoed as it is and the function doesn't run. I have tried my best, searched online etc. But there seems no way to do it.

Is there a way to run a JavaScript function from PHP script?

Comment: And how do you insert that output from AJAX to your page?

Comment: use EVAl() function.To run the js code.

Comment: Are you aware of the several syntax errors? Or this is not the exact code you tried. Also, we will need more details to understand what are you trying to do, when are you trying to run this.

Comment: @Oyeme An even better idea: don't use the `eval()` function :)

Comment: @bažmegakapa actually I want to call the function from the php script. The function will change the referenced div.

Comment: @TheNoble-Coder I understand, you already wrote that. I mean: how do you call this PHP? Is this a PHP that responds to an AJAX request with HTML? What is the Ajax code? Without details, you won't get the best answers you could.

Comment: PHP is a serverside language.  There is no way for a php script to call a javascript function.  When a PHP script is run, all it can do is return an HTTP response.  That response can be whatever you like, but it is up to the client to handle it.  If you are trying to return snippets of javascript code that you want to execute, then you would have to do what Oyeme suggested and eval.  There are simpler and better solutions to updating the content of the div, by manipulating the DOM, using Ajax as F. Calderan suggested.  I'd highly recommend jquery to simplify this for you.

Comment: @bažmegakapa yea,the question was,'How to run a JavaScript function from PHP script?' - I have answered,how to run it :),I know it's a not good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should manage the code execution on client-side. let say your php script called via ajax is

```
?php
   if(isset($_REQUEST['change-div'])) {
      echo 'UpdateDiv';
      exit();
   }
?>
```

Then your Ajax success callback (I'm framework agnostic here) could be simply

```
...
success : function(response) {
    if (response === 'UpdateDiv') {
       UpdateDiv();
    }
}
```

In this way you will keep client-side and server-side logic well separated. You won't also  need to inject javascript code (changing your DOM structure) or use `eval()`